# Will FreeNAS run on a 2011 Mac Mini?

Tags: mac-mini, freenas

Is it possible to run FreeNAS on a mid-2011 Mac Mini? What steps need to be taken to install it and make it boot successfully?

Comment: Why don't you try it out on a VM?

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: Because if it runs on a VM which is (massively underspec'd) - it'll most likely run on the MAC mini..

Comment: I'm more concerned about getting a non-Mac OS to actually boot on Mac hardware. The small number of articles I could find about running FreeBSD on the mac mini seemed to indicate that it isn't straightforward. A VM (by design) would abstract away the mac-specific issues and not be a useful simulation.